# How to parse JSON from input field

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am trying to parse the json data from an input field on my node.js server. If I simply have the value 16 as a value in the input field, I can simply read it out with `request.body.id` (`<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="16"/>)`. But when I stringify a json as a value of the input field and parse the data of json, I always get an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`. But I can see in the browser console my json data  `<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{" a":0.3,"b":0.5,"c":1.3}">` Why can't I read the value of the input field with `request.body.id`?

Comment: Please post the string that causes the parser error. Add a `console.log` before `JSON.parse`.

Comment: You're probably only sending `{`. The attribute is `value="{"`. Replace `value="{" a":0.3,"b":0.5,"c":1.3}"` with `value="{\" a\":0.3,\"b\":0.5,\"c\":1.3}"`

Comment: @jabaa I have already tried it, but I always get nothing back. I only get an open curly brace without closing brace. `{` But as I mentioned, I can see my json in the browser inspection.

Comment: @jabaa How can I do that? I have an object like this `data = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}`and then stringify it like this `var json = JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to the question. In the question you have hardcoded JSON in HTML that causes a specific problem. A possible solution is in my answer. Are you generating the HTML with something like `'<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="' + json + '">'` in JavaScript?

Comment: @jabaa yes. I have it in a string template like this `'<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="${json}"/>'`

Comment: @jabaa No, I can see in browser inspection my json like this `value="{" a":0.3,"b":0.5,"c":1.3}"`. But in my Javascript I have this `value="${json}"/>`.

Comment: @jabaa Thank you, it helped. It works when I use `value='${json}'`.

Comment: It won't work if the JSON contains a single quote. You can try `{ "a": "This won't work" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{" a":0.3,"b":0.5,"c":1.3}">
```

contains the attributes

```
type="hidden"
id="id"
name="id"
value="{"
```

and some garbage

```
a":0.3,"b":0.5,"c":1.3}"
```

because the first quote in your JSON closes the attribute.

You have to masquerade the quotes

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{&quot; a&quot;:0.3,&quot;b&quot;:0.5,&quot;c&quot;:1.3}">
```

After clarification in the comments here is a working example:

```js
const json = JSON.stringify({" a":0.3,"b":0.5,"c":1.3});

document.body.innerHTML = `<input value="${json.replaceAll('"', '&quot;')}">`;
const input = document.querySelector('input');

console.log(JSON.parse(input.value));
```

Comment: `value="{\" a\":0.3,\"b\":0.5,\"c\":1.3}"` will not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to send only the JSON data to the server while calling the respective endpoint in the front-end application. You should not send the html directly to the node js end-point